# Share common polymer elements

Tags: polymer

I am using polymer core and paper components to build my app, working great! But when I want to deploy my app to production I don't have a clear way of knowing what all common polymer dependencies I have to package with my app and shared those common elements across multiple apps.

For example:

To use https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button, I include a link to ../paper-button/paper-button.html which might have other dependencies. I used vulcanize but it seems to inline all components which is not an ideal (in terms of size) way to share via a CDN.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Bower, or another dependency management framework.  Using bower, you can declare what the dependencies of your app are:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#master",
    "paper-button": "Polymer/paper-button#master"
  }
}
```

and then use `bower install` to add those dependencies to your application.  The benefit there is that bower will then install the dependencies of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and so on.

With bower you could run `bower list` and it will list the dependency hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use bower, or have trouble setting it up, the [Polymer Elements Catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) does a pretty good job of providing an archive of the components you want with all the appropriate dependencies.